# What causes apparently random “digital watch” beeping alarms on F32?

Tags: fedora, audio

### Context

I have recently updated from Fedora 31 to Fedora 32 (on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon — but I'm not sure it's relevant).

### Problem

Since the update, I'm experiencing beeping alarm sound at apparently random times; which is quite annoying.

What I've noticed so far:

- The alarms sounds like *“a digital watch alarm”*, as described in [this subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/flwqpr/fedora_32_beeping_alarms_how_to_disable/). However, unlike what the feedback comment says, it didn't stopped after a `dnf` upgrade for me. Moreover, I've only used post-released Fedora 32, and not beta (as in the subreddit).
- The alarm sound is different from the terminal bell / alert sound.
- The alarm goes off about a couple times a day. It lasts around 10 seconds. Time seems consistent from day to day, and to occur at “round times”: e.g., 08:50, 12:15, etc.
- Alarms do not seem to be related to any calendar event. As far as I remember, they were still here when I uninstalled GNOME-Calendar.
- Alarms are not related to GNOME-Clocks alarms.
- There are no cron jobs running (neither for my user, nor for `root`)

### Questions

What causes these alarms? How to disable them?

Comment: Well, it rang at 10:03 today, so I guess the part about regularity is wrong…

Comment: The sound I hear is actually the `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga` file playing. I'm still investigating which program causes it to be played.

Comment: OMG. I have the same issue and it's so painfully annoying. For me it always triggers 5min before the daily team meeting. Any solution is appreciated here!

Comment: I've opened: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-calendar/-/issues/652

Comment: @JulianStecklina the quick (and dirty!) solution is to delete/rename the file so that it effectively cannot be played any more. Or replace it with Pachelbel's cannon, as you wish…

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the program playing it was Evolution.
The sounds can be [turned off in Evolution 3.34.1 and higher](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/-/issues/1032#note_1311481) (unreleased at the time of writing) in the Settings or via:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar notify-enable-audio false
```

Here's a general approach to find out what program causes it:

1. Install `auditd` (usually the `audit` or `auditd` package)
2. Configure a watch on the sound file by creating `/etc/audit/rules.d/alarm-clock.rules` with the following content:

   ```
   -w /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga -p rwxa -k alarm-clock
   ```

   And load the rule:

   ```
   $ sudo augenrules --load
   ```
3. Wait for the sound to happen
4. Check the audit log:

   ```
   $ sudo grep alarm-clock /var/log/audit/audit.log
   type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1604335160.733:102): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=13 a0=ffffff9c a1=23ce800 a2=0 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1664 pid=2045 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=1000 suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=1 comm="evolution-alarm" exe="/usr/libexec/evolution-data-server/evolution-alarm-notify" subj==unconfined key="alarm-clock"
   type=PATH msg=audit(1604335160.733:102): item=0 name="/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/alarm-clock-elapsed.oga" inode=3213038 dev=00:24 mode=0100644 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
   ```

   The `comm=` and `exe=` elements may point to the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling gnome-clocks solved the random alarm at 11:00 for me.

There is an issue at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-clocks/-/issues/102 which got closed unfortunately.